# Integrating Files

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I am writing a console application in C++ and I want it at runtime to pass data to another Windows form application. This Windows form application will then draw what I want (a circle).

How can integrate both files so when I run the .cpp file and the file will add items to the form application to be drawn? I try to call the .cpp file using

```
// Create the main window and run it
Application::Run(gcnew Form1());
```

but this method did not work. Is there any way to use my console application to pass the parameters to my Windows form application?

Comment: You know... take some English lessons... and then try again. Sorry. This simply doesn't make any sense at all. :/

Comment: No offense, but If you don't put at least some effort in your questions, why should we put effort in our answers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to modify your Windows form application to include a public function that receives parameters (dimensions, shape to be drawn, etc.), and calls it's internal functions to draw the appropriate shape/features.

Comment: thanks do you have exampls so i can follow and how can i run the .cpp file